# Shortcut key to open a class or a file in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've googled around for an answer to this - can't find one.

In Intellij, if you want to open an arbitrary class, you press ctrl-n, you get a little text box where you can type the name of a class or just the camel caps initials or some wildcards.

Same with files - ctrl-shift-n.

What is the keystroke to do this in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: Why they put this "Navigate To..." to the Edit menu? Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is more of a "search everything" than IntelliJ's Ctrl+N equivalent. There is no way to only search classes that I know of. Coming from IntelliJ, you will be thoroughly disappointed with Visual Studio.